# When should one do Synchronous or Asynchronous sending?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

**Synchronous calls** : calls that will send and expect a reply.(will block current process)

**Asynchronous calls** : calls that will send(Wont block current process)

Though I understand the concept of what sync and async are,but when it comes to converting these concept in to [code](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines#game-trading-between-two-players),I usually fail.

[This link](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines#a-trading-system-specification) explains how deadlocks can be avoided by choosing async calls to send data with other processes and sync calls to send data to itself.

My Question : How can a person choose over sync or async calls while making a real world application in erlang/OTP.

Comment: Could you be a bit more concrete? Both sync and async calls have their merits. "Will block all other activities" does not make sense in Erlang, sync calls will just "block" your current process.

Comment: The decision making,when should i block my current process or when i shouldnt?Hope i am clear..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my rules of thumb:

1. -> use asynchronous message
2. -> if your process need a result and cannot do something in between you may use synchronous message (easier to read)
3. -> if your process need a result and must not do anything in between use use synchronous call

Answer (score 0):

When you a deciding what to use, try ask yourself this questions:

- Do I need call's result?
- Is it important to me if call fails? How do I know about this?
- Is receiving side capable to handle all async calls with the same speed as they arrive? What will happen if not?

One important point about sync/async calls is overload protection. Try to divide you program flow in to concurrent entities, which must proportionally slows down when load is increasing, so you can estimate how many units of such work you can exec.